# Remove 'home' link from breadcrumb

Tags: php, yii, breadcrumbs

I have breadcrumbs such as `Home > Instance > Action` in all my view pages. How can I remove the 'Home' link from all the breadcrumbs?

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Keypairs'=>array('admin'),
'Manage',
);
```

Comment: I think you have to customise the `breadcrumbs` function.

Comment: you could also go into gii's code and delete the code for future crud generator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done by setting the [`homeLink` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs#homeLink-detail) to `false`, in your CBreadcrumbs widget initialization. This is usually done in a layout file.

In the default Yii app, in *protected/views/layouts/main.php*:

```
<?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
        'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
        'homeLink'=>false // add this line
    )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 2):

in layouts/main.php add 'homeLink' => false

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
     'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs'])? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
     'homeLink' => false
]) ?>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer of nearly 7 years ago?

Comment: my answer helps for yii2 version. 'zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs' existed in yii1.1